# How to empty the data using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to empty the data(img) when someone clicks in another button.

```
%div(class="backend-unit")
%h2 Delete cars
%small Select the make then the year to see all the cars that belong to it
%br
=   select_tag("year", options_for_select(Car.all.order(year: 'asc').pluck(:year).uniq))
- @makes.each do |make|
    %button(class="get-cars" id="#{make.id}") #{make.name}
%div(id="render-cars")
```

So when clicks in another make, which is a button the it will empty the previous data and show the new one.

```
    $('button#car-model').click(function(){
                var modelData = $(this).text()
                $.ajax({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: '/cars/' + year + '/' + make_id + '/' + modelData,
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function(data){
                        $('div#render-cars').empty();
                        $('div#render-cars').html(data);
                    }
                });
```

However the previous data is still there and when you click in another button is just keeps adding. Any idea why?

Comment: i think you can just do $('#render-cars').empty();

Comment: How about `$('div#render-cars').html("");`

Comment: @blackmind that sorts of works though, however as soon as you click in another make button it appends after the data(img). Not until I click in the button#car-model the previous data clear and shows the recent.

Comment: @PamelaGuerrero could you make a fiddle or a code-runner here.

Comment: Remove `$('div#render-cars').empty();`, because `$('div#render-cars').html(data);` is enough, it will replace your `div#render-cars` with new content of `data`